# Trying to format a bookdown book without gitbook output

Tags: bookdown

Responding to the first reply.

I am trying to build a bookdown book that's not gitbook. Yet no matter what i try to include by way of css or yaml, I still get the same gitbook result.

Below I'll show the index file and then the results of the build. It all works, but it is gitbook, not what I would have expected - something from the more generic html_book format.

I'm new to all of this, but am a very seasoned LaTeX author and pretty familiar with css.

But I'm having real trouble here - my basic goal is to render a serif font! That seems to be a struggle?!

Thanks in advance for help...

Ray

Here is the simple index file - now passed through jsonformatter...

```
--- 
title: 'Against the Grain'
author: 'Raymond Brock'
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
site: 'bookdown::bookdown_site'
'bookdown::html_book': null
output:
    html_document:
        theme: darkly
        highlight: espresso
        toc: true
        toc_float: true
documentclass: book
bibliography:
    - book.bib
    - packages.bib
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: 'This is an investgation of two rebels of the 16th century.'
---
```

Then there are multiple chapters which work fine, just not looking as I'd expect.

However, the result is a regular gitbook as the build shows. Where was it told to do output_format = 'bookdown::gitbook'??

The results of the build:

```
    ==> rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::gitbook', encoding = 'UTF-8')



    processing file: against-the-grain.Rmd
      |.................................................................| 100%
       inline R code fragments


    output file: against-the-grain.knit.md

    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS against-the-grain.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output against-the-grain.html --email-obfuscation none --wrap preserve --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/bookdown/templates/gitbook.html --highlight-style pygments --number-sections --include-in-header /var/folders/73/fmvtgv_n4f57sjqblbh8439c0000gn/T//Rtmpwmh6tv/rmarkdown-strda8c185d45aa.html --mathjax --filter /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc-citeproc 

    Output created: _book/index.html
    Warning message:
    In split_chapters(output, gitbook_page, number_sections, split_by,  :
      You have 7 Rmd input file(s) but only 6 first-level heading(s). Did you forget first-level headings in certain Rmd files?
```

Gitbook is being invoked from somewhere! I had changed the shell script also to:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ev

Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd')"
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::pdf_book')"
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::epub_book')"
```

Comment: I have tried to format the sample code, but the YAML headers don't line up correctly. Can you please make sure that the header file presented here is exactly as you have it + an indent of 4 spaces? This way it will be correctly formatted as source code.

Comment: BTW, the documentation lists other HTML based output formats: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response. To be sure I went to jasonformatter and checked the yaml and you're right. I'll paste it in a new comment...

Comment: Please [edit] your question with appropriate formatting instead of putting things like this into the comment, where they are unreadable.

Comment: Sorry. New stackoverflow poster.

Comment: I edited the original question with the added information.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#bootstrap-style) one can use `bookdown::html_book` as output format, e.g.

```
--- 
title: 'Against the Grain'
author: 'Raymond Brock'
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
site: 'bookdown::bookdown_site'
output:
    bookdown::html_book:
        theme: darkly
        highlight: espresso
        toc: true
        toc_float: true
description: 'This is an investgation of two rebels of the 16th century.'
---
```

(I have removed the bibliography related things for simplicity.)